# How to sync multiple MongoDB instances?

Tags: database, mongodb

I have a service on a remote server (server1) that uses a MongoDB database. Now i want to copy that service and the database to a second server (server2) to have a failsafe in case server1 has any problems.

How would i go about synchronizing the database so it's always the same on both servers and so that when server1 goes up after a problem it migrates any changes made to server2's database to it's own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a replica set of your Server 1. MongoDB provides this feature.

There is an extensive explanation on [MongoDB Replication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/replication/) in Mongo's Official Documentation.